# How to duplicate noise similar to this black and white-picture

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, texture

I want to do something similiar like this picture in Gimp (or Photoshop if required). Any ideas on how to proceed? Anything useful will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: At the top right if you search for [noise](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=noise) A huge list of similar questions will show up.  Others that may help are [How do I reduce noise in an image?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7581/how-do-i-reduce-noise-in-an-image) and [How to make a noise/paper background in PS](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7044/how-to-remove-noise-grain-on-a-picture-based-on-some-noise-pattern)

Comment: Also google 'film grain effects'

Answer (score 1):

The noise part is pretty simple. In Photoshop, create a new layer and fill it white. Go `Filter > Noise > Add Noise`. After you've adjusted it to your liking, change the blend mode on the layer to multiply and place it above the rest of your image.